# review task: test failed

Tags: support, review-audit

I today did a review task. I noticed the answer by a new user was a copy paste of an earlier exactly same answer that I read on the site by a trusted user. So I flagged the answer as needing moderator attention (for plagiarism).

I received the following warning:

> STOP! Look and Listen.
>
> This was an audit, designed to see if you were paying attention. You
>   didn't pass. Your review was inappropriate. This was a high quality
>   post and you should have considered leaving it as-is or even upvoting.
>
> Don't worry, we've already handled this post appropriately – but
>   please take a minute to look it over closely, keeping in mind the
>   guidance above.

well obviously the review should not be failed, as I correctly detected the answer being a copy....

Comment: Yet another program fails the Turing Test!

Comment: Unfortunately this is not a bug as much as a feature. My suggestion is to always open the post on a separate page, and see what's going on.

Comment: See [this answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/16897/8348).